# Django Server not starting because of RestFramework

Tags: django

Each time i include the Django Rest Framework in my installed apps in my settings.py file, I get an error while starting my server.

The Error Message below:

Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner self.run()
File"C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run self._target(*self._args, **self.*kwargs)
File "C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception raise *exception[1]
File "C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init**.py", line 375, in execute autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django_*init**.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate app_config.ready()
File "C:\Users\gchukwuma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\apps.py", line 10, in ready from .checks import pagination_system_check  # NOQA
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

The Settings.py file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

```py
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'base.apps.BaseConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework'

]
```

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Also, we need your exception

Comment: I just added the Error message and also the settings.py file. Hope this helps because I am stuck.